# Onde o retorno é List<List<String>> converter esse resultado em apenas List<String> combinando os elementos

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, kotlin

Considerando a implementação abaixo:

```
fun main(list: List<String>) {
    val x = 
        list
            .stream()
            .map { findMessages(it) }
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
}


fun findMessages(s: String) : List<String> {
    // return some list of strings   
}
```

Eu atribui a implementação para x, porém esse x é está tipado como `List<List<String>>`. Caso eu tire o `collect(Collectors.toList())` ficaria como `Stream<List<String>>`.

Mas o que eu gostaria de ter mesmo é um `List<String>` onde cada lista retornada pelo método `findMessages()` realizasse um 'merge' com a lista anterior, porém não estou conseguindo achar um jeito simples de fazer isso.

Uma solução alternativa seria essa:

```
 fun main(list: List<String>) {
  val messagesToInput: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    val x = 
        list
            .stream()
            .map { findMessages(it) }
            .map { it -> it.stream().map { messagesToInput.add(it) } }
}
```

Mas creio que existiria uma maneira mais eficaz do que criar uma lista e atribuir a ela as mensagens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `flatMap` para "achatar" os resultados em um único nível, trazendo de `Stream<List<String>>` para apenas o conteúdo das streams `List<String>`:

```
    val x = 
        list
            .stream()
            .flatMap { findMessages(it).stream() }
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
```